# Sub Queries using Select

Tags: sql-server, select, subquery

I have two tables Shifts and Leaves

Table: **Shifts** has following fields:

Id, ShiftName,

Table: **Leaves** has following fields:

EmpId, Shiftid, ApplyDate, DateFrom, DateTo

What I want to do is I want to select the ShiftName from **Shifts** table based on the Shiftid from **Leaves** table.

**I tried:**

```
select tbl_Sm.ShiftName in (select Shiftid from Leaves tbl_Lm where tbl_Sm.Id = tbl_Lm.Shiftid)
from Shifts tbl_Sm
```

But it gives me this error:

[image]

What would be the correct approach?

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected results so we can be sure we are all working on the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `inner join` to achieve it

```
select s.ShiftName -- l.EmpId, l.Shiftid, 
from Leaves l
inner join Shifts s on s.Id = l.Shiftid
```

Comment: What is -- in the middle?

Comment: Just comment code, If you want to get the columns, you just need to remove `--`.
It should be `select s.ShiftName, l.EmpId, l.Shiftid`

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be querying it backwards, if you want the ShiftName for a Leaves records, you need to query Leaves, sub-query Shifts e.g.

```
select
  (select tbl_sm.ShiftName from Shifts tbl_Sm where tbl_Sm.Id = tbl_Lm.ShiftId)
from Leaves tbl_Lm
```

Demonstration:

```
declare @Shifts table (ShiftName varchar(128), id int identity(1,1))
declare @Leaves table (ShiftId int)

insert into @Shifts(ShiftName)
  select 'Day'
  union all select 'Night'

insert into @Leaves(ShiftId)
  select 1
  union all select 2

select
  (select tbl_sm.ShiftName from @Shifts tbl_Sm where tbl_Sm.Id = tbl_Lm.ShiftId)
from @Leaves tbl_Lm
```

Results:

```
ShiftName
---------
Day
Night
```

Comment: This gives me an error saying " Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression. "

Comment: Please provide some sample data as this can only happen if you have duplicate shift ids

Comment: It should be `select tbl_sm.ShiftName from Shifts tbl_Sm where tbl_Sm.Id = tbl_Lm.ShiftId` or `select * from (select tbl_sm.ShiftName from Shifts tbl_Sm where tbl_Sm.Id = tbl_Lm.ShiftId) a`

Comment: @Phong your first query is exactly what I have?